# Select highest occuring value per user PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I've got a table of user IDs, and values. I'd like to select the most frequently occuring value per user.

Here's what the table looks like...

```
UserID  |  Value
--------------------
501     |    1
501     |    1
24      |    2
55      |    1
55      |    1
55      |    3
```

So I'd like my query output table to look like...

```
UserID  |  Value
--------------------
501     |    1
24      |    2
55      |    1
```

Comment: I see your comment about `most frequently occurring value`. what happens when `UserID` have 2 (or more) equally most occurring values? which one choose then?

Comment: I don't really mind which one get's picked.

Comment: So, doesn't matters ?

Comment: Yeah I think in these cases either is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using `count` and `row_number` window functions, like this:

```
select UserID, Value  from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by UserID order by cnt desc) as rn from (
        select your_table.*, count(*) over(partition by UserID, Value) as cnt from your_table
    ) t
) tt
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `group by` and `count()` like

```
select UserID,  count(`Value`) as `value`
from tbl1
group by UserID  
order by count(`Value`) desc
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I meant most frequently occurring value!

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the highest occurring value for user 55 in your example would be 3 right?

```
select max(Value), UserID
from table
group by UserID
```

EDIT: what Rahul said.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I meant most frequently occurring value!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(id)
  id,
  value
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      value,
      count(value) AS cnt
    FROM
      tbl
    GROUP BY id, value
  ) mq
ORDER BY id, cnt DESC
```